# IE 11 Warning after changing Home Page in the registry

Tags: c#, windows, internet-explorer, registry, internet-explorer-11

In my C# application I need to set the Home Page for the users of a PC. I know that you need to change this registry key

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main
```

and set

```
Start Page = "my_start_page"
```

The problem is that when I first launch IE after the change, I get this warning

[image]

Anyone knows how I can get rid of it?

Comment: That website sucks.  Just host the image on imgur and add a link to it in an [edit].  Someone with enough rep will edit it into your question.

Comment: @Will, thanks, edited.

Comment: Bzzzt! You're doing it wrong. Applications should not change a user's default home page (or any other system settings). If the user wants to configure this, they can use their browser's properties to do it.

Comment: @CodyGray I see your point, but hte goal of the application is to setup a User Account according to the company default settings, so I need to change the default page programmatically and not let the user do it.

Comment: You should be using Deployment Services or sysprep or equivalent for this. I haven't kept up with how things have changed for Windows 10, but for Windows 7, you'd do something like this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/973289. This is a question that would be asked on Super User or Server Fault. It isn't something you write an application to do.

Comment: Ok I understand. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Or in a domain environment you could do it via a GPO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting this registry key will remove it.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_EUPP_GLOBAL_FORCE_DISABLE]
"iexplore.exe"=dword:00000001
```

I also use this key stop the "welcome" tab from appearing.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
"DisableFirstRunCustomize"=dword:00000001
```